# Compute mean and variance on specific columns of 2D array only if a condition on element on each row is satisfied

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array with dimension (690L, 15L).
I need to compute a columns wise mean on this dataset only in some particolar columns, but with a condition: I need to include a row if and only if an element in the same row at specific column satisfy a condition. Let's me more cleare with some code.

```
f = open("data.data")
dataset =  np.loadtxt(fname = f, delimiter = ',')
```

I have array with fullfilled with indexes where I need to perform mean (and variance)

```
index_catego = [0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11]
```

The condition is that the `dataset[i, 14] == 1`
As output I want an 1D array with length like `len(index_catego)` where each element of this array is the mean of the previously columns

```
output = [mean_of_index_0, mean_of_index_3, ..., mean_of_index_11]
```

I am using Python recently but I am sure there is a cool way of doing this with `np.where`, `mask`, `np.mean` or something else.

I already implement a solution, but it is not elegant and I am not sure if it is correct.

```
import numpy as np

index_catego = [0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11]

matrix_mean_positive = []
matrix_variance_positive = []
matrix_mean_negative = []
matrix_variance_negative = []

n_positive = 0
n_negative = 0

sum_positive = np.empty(len(index_catego))
sum_negative = np.empty(len(index_catego))


for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
    if dataset[i, 14] == 0:
        n_positive = n_positive + 1
        j = 0
        for k in index_catego:
            sum_positive[j] = sum_positive[j] + dataset[i, k]
            j = j + 1
    else:
        n_negative = n_negative + 1
        j = 0
        for k in index_catego:
            sum_negative[j] = sum_negative[j] + dataset[i, k]
            j = j + 1

for item in np.nditer(sum_positive):
    matrix_mean_positive.append(item / n_positive)

for item in np.nditer(sum_negative):
    matrix_mean_negative.append(item / n_negative)

print(matrix_mean_positive)
print(matrix_mean_negative)
```

If you wanna try your solution, I put some data example

```
1,22.08,11.46,2,4,4,1.585,0,0,0,1,2,100,1213,0
0,22.67,7,2,8,4,0.165,0,0,0,0,2,160,1,0
0,29.58,1.75,1,4,4,1.25,0,0,0,1,2,280,1,0
0,21.67,11.5,1,5,3,0,1,1,11,1,2,0,1,1
1,20.17,8.17,2,6,4,1.96,1,1,14,0,2,60,159,1
0,15.83,0.585,2,8,8,1.5,1,1,2,0,2,100,1,1
1,17.42,6.5,2,3,4,0.125,0,0,0,0,2,60,101,0
```

Thanks for you help.

**UPDATE 1:** 
I tried with this

```
output_positive = dataset[:, index_catego][dataset[:, 14] == 0]
mean_p = output_positive.mean(axis = 0)
print(mean_p)

output_negative = dataset[:, index_catego][dataset[:, 14] == 1]
mean_n = output_negative.mean(axis = 0)
print(mean_n)
```

but means computed by the first (solution not cool) and the second solution (one line cool solotion) are all different.
I checked what `dataset[:, index_catego][dataset[:, 14] == 0]` and `dataset[:, index_catego][dataset[:, 14] == 1]` select and seems correct (right dimension and right element).

**UPDATE 2:**
Ok, the first solution is wrong because (for example) the first column have as element only 0 and 1, but as mean return a value > 1. I do not know where I failed. Seems that the positive class is correct (or at least plausible), while negative class are not even plausible.

So, is it second solution correct? Is there a better way of doing it?

**UPDATE 3:**
I think I found the problem with the first solution: I am using jupyter notebook and sometimes (not all the times) when I rerun the same cell where the first solution is, element in `matrix_mean_positive` and `matrix_mean_negative` are doubled. If someone know why, could be point me?

Now both solution return the same means.

Comment: `dataset[:, index_catego][dataset[:, 14] == 0]` could be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do Kernel->Restart in jupyter notebook to clean the memory before rerun